# Bank sent int'l transfer to wrong beneficiary using wrong currency - when returned it was $2200 less because of conversion fees. Who's at fault?

Tags: transfer, eur-euro

At the end of May '23 I walked into my local WF branch with the instructions from WISE Bank on how to wire 72,000 euros to their Belgian branch. This was my first international transfer.  The banker for some reason had me change the Beneficiary to my name, and to my lawyer's address and decided to send it in USD ($77,500) I signed the paperwork because the banker told me this is how it had to be done.

Of course the transfer is denied but not before it goes untraceable for almost 3 weeks. When returned to my account it's $2200 short &  WF says they are not responsible for conversion losses. They've asked for no documentation from me ( the transfer instructions I gave them) and refuse to acknowledge that their rep changed the transfer details. Having done numerous transfers since then I now know the rules & regs - which makes it even more infuriating because this transfer order was wrong in so many ways. But, again I was doing what the banker told me had to be done.

Do banks have a "Mediation" dept? It's ridiculous that this would have to go to court when the law (UCC Article 4) is clear. The bank did not follow my instructions(4-A 302) and per 4-A 305 (iii) *issuance of a payment order that does not comply with the terms of the payment order of the originator, the bank is liable to the originator for its expenses in the funds transfer and for incidental expenses and interest losses*

Any other remedies besides calling my lawyer?

Comment: If you signed the transfer request and the bank executed what was in that request then the bank did follow your instructions. I suggest you talk to an attorney if you want to consider legal action.

Comment: It was the bank that told me I had to change the transfer request and the proof I have is the document/ instructions that I brought in and they copied. If you're right then banks have no liability when it comes to dispensing instructions and 4-A 302 is moot: "(1) The receiving bank is obliged to issue, on the execution date, a payment order complying with the sender's order and to follow the sender's instructions" The payment order did not comply with my order and instructions.

Comment: The instructions is what you signed. It doesn't matter what was in your pocket

Comment: No, I signed the Payment Order.  This is the standard for "Erroneous Payment"   4-A 205: "(a) If an accepted payment order was transmitted pursuant to a security procedure for the detection of error and the payment order (i) erroneously instructed payment to a beneficiary not intended by the sender" " (a), the sender is not obliged to pay the order and the receiving bank is entitled to recover from the beneficiary any amount paid to the beneficiary to the extent allowed by the law governing mistake and restitution."  You're saying the bank did not err in changing my instructions.

Comment: From what you're describing, the bank didn't change your instructions - you did. Bottom line, if you want to go to court - talk to a lawyer.

Comment: Here's the thing, the incorrect Payment Order I signed was for a transfer of $77,500 USD.  I did not sign anything that talked about conversion to euros. The intermediary bank made the conversion and per the UCC it is the responsibility of the receiving bank (WF) to go after losses from the intermediary.  At the end of the day - Wells Fargo did not follow their own protocols. It was their job to know they could not transfer USD into a Euro account - the same way I cannot deposit euros into my USD account.

Comment: Sending US$ to a Euro account just means that the conversion happens on the receiving end and is done by the receiving bank. There's nothing weird or wrong with that - it's just a choice you make when initiating the payment (much like choosing US$ or local currency when using a credit-card while travelling). WF didn't do anything wrong just by sending US$ to a Euro account. Ultimately, everything written on the transfer instruction form *which you signed* is your instruction to WF. Anything else you may have given to them is largely irrelevant.

Comment: Actually sending US$ to a Euro-only account is not possible with certain banks using the IBAN system and it is immediately rejected, per the beneficiary bank. In the same way I cannot deposit euros into my US bank account without converting. I wired $77,500 USD, a rejected transfer means that $77,500 goes back into my account.   The basis of the transaction was in dollars and there is nowhere in the WF Payment Order that says $ will be converted to euros.

Answer (score 0):

Consider contacting [Consumer Finance Protection](https://consumerfinance.gov) (CFPB). You can file a complaint with them. I don't have any personal experience with CFPB but I've read that companies take the complaints very seriously.